# How to stop Prettier forcing <span> to the new line

Tags: prettier

I have this code

```
<a class="logo" href="">Web<span class="logo-part">Studio</span></a>
```

Prettier formats it in this way:

```
<a class="logo" href="">
  Web
  <span class="logo-part">Studio</span>
</a>
```

so the rendered page has an unwanted space between the words.

I've tried changing the **HTML whitespace sensitivity** to strict and ignore, but it doesn't work.
Could someone suggest what other setting may cause this behavior?

Prettier Options:

```
{
  "arrowParens": "always",
  "bracketSpacing": true,
  "endOfLine": "lf",
  "htmlWhitespaceSensitivity": "ignore",
  "insertPragma": false,
  "singleAttributePerLine": false,
  "bracketSameLine": true,
  "jsxBracketSameLine": false,
  "jsxSingleQuote": false,
  "printWidth": 80,
  "proseWrap": "preserve",
  "quoteProps": "as-needed",
  "requirePragma": false,
  "semi": true,
  "singleQuote": false,
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "trailingComma": "es5",
  "useTabs": false,
  "embeddedLanguageFormatting": "auto",
  "vueIndentScriptAndStyle": false,
  "filepath": "d:\\test.html",
  "parser": "html"
}
```

Comment: How are you running Prettier? The latest version seems to put the span on the same line as "Web": https://prettier.io/playground/

Comment: I'm running it in VSCode 1.86.2. I see that it works as intended on the playground. 
It seems I need to investigate which setting may have an impact on this.
Initially, I didn’t change anything except HTML whitespace sensitivity. As for now, I've tried to change these: end of line, prose wrap, bracket same line, with no success. I configure these settings directly in the VSCode UI

Comment: Try updating your Prettier extension version (if not latest). When you format your code, you should see an object of "Prettier Options" in the VS Code output tab (next to Debug Console and Terminal). Can you update your post with those options?

Comment: I just checked, and the latest version is already installed. 
Sure, added Prettier options